# Not Getting the desired Output in PHP

Tags: php, html

My code looks completely correct.I just copied it from New Boston php tutorial,its working there. But its not working properly here. Every time after the submission else block get executed and it produces the output "Please fill the form". If I filled all the fields than if block should get executed, and it should print the 'contact_name', 'contact_email', 'contact_text', but its not.I am writing this code in netbeans.

here is the code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['contact_name']) && isset($_POST['contact_email'])
    isset($_POST['contact_text']))
    {
        echo $contact_name=$_POST['contact_name'];
        echo $contact_email=$_POST['contact_email'];
        echo $contact_text=$_POST['contact_text'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Please fill the form';
    }
?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    Name:<br><input type="text" name="=contact_name"><br><br>
    Email address:<br><input type="text" name="contact_email"><br><br>
    Message:<br>
    <textarea name="contact_text" rows="6" cols="30"></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: one more thing `if(isset($_POST['contact_name']) && isset($_POST['contact_email'])
    isset($_POST['contact_text']))` you have missed `&&` after `isset($_POST['contact_email'])` so add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
  Name:<br><input type="text" name="=contact_name"><br><br>
```

With

```
  Name:<br><input type="text" name="contact_name"><br><br>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your `contact_name` field:

Change this:`<input type="text" name="=contact_name">`

to this: `<input type="text" name="contact_name">`

Answer (score 0):

There is an error of  `name="=contact_name"`

Remove extra =

```
name="contact_name"
```